# How to see the device list of a given Google account

Tags: security, google-account, device-administrator

I have many test Android devices and added my Google account to those device to reuse my application collection.

Recently I often recieve payment notification via gmail for application which I really don't buy. So my need is to see the list of devices which has been added the account to.

This also related to the situation when someone try to use my account on their device and read my email/download my application.

So my question is "How to see the device list of a given Google account"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just visit [My Android Apps](https://play.google.com/apps) with your browser, and log in with your account. This will list your devices and apps.

Another good place is the [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard), which is even more detailed in some respects (shows EMEI on GSM handsets for example), less in others (thanx, @ewanm89).

Comment: there's also a per device listing for installed apps

Comment: Correct (and up-to-date as long one didn't bring a device offline and then removed/side-installed things w/o bringing that device online again ;). And you can uninstall apps from there as well. Somebody told me you can even copy apps between devices from that place -- but I couldn't figure this one out yet.

Comment: You google dashboard also gives some information, more detailed in some respects (shows EMEI on GSM handsets for example), less in others: https://www.google.com/dashboard/

Comment: @ewanm89 Thank you, didn't think of that -- integrated it with my answer to make it easier to find.

Comment: @Izzy I find nothing other than the google search home page when open `Google Dashboard`. Do you know why?

Comment: @NamG.VU no idea -- it works for me. Did you log in with your Google account? Besides: The Dashboard was brought up by ewanm89, maybe he can tell...